# What is the difference between CAML Offset and OffsetDays?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What is the difference between CAML **Offset** and **OffsetDays**?

I'm familiar with [Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460496.aspx) and I'm using it and it is working as i expect. today I've read an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa981241(v=office.14).aspx) that use the OffsetDays, but there is no description for this proprietary on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Offset` and `OffsetDays` are same.

**See comments, `OffsetDays` is the correct one to use**

Microsoft as always failed to document this.

**This link no longer exists**:
http://techmotley.com/2012/01/27/correct-offset-for-today-in-caml-queries/

Comment: Just a word of caution: using CAML queries in PowerShell, I have just run into an issue where Offset was ignored (unfortunately it also didn't throw an error so it went under the radar for a little while). 

Changing it to OffsetDays the query returned the correct results.

So Offset and OffsetDays are apparently not ALWAYS the same. This was on SP2013 on-premise.

Comment: Link reference here is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Scenario 1 : If you are checking for the items having "Due Date" field value as "Today", then this would be the query for you:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="DueDate" />
        <Value Type="DateTime">
            <Today/>
        </Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

Scenario 2 : what if you want something dynamic?
 Ex. If you want to get the items, having "Due Date" 5 days before Today. For this you can't give a static day, because "Today" changes daily.
     Option is "OffsetDays".
The Query goes like this :

```
 <Where>
     <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="DueDate" />
         <Value Type="DateTime">
             <Today OffsetDays="-5" />  ----------> for future dates the value should be positive.
         </Value>
     </Eq>
 </Where>
```

In many documents they have mentioned Offset instead of "OffsetDays"... better be careful while checking...